# HTTP 504 error AWS ElasticBeanstalk for a Python application

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, timeout, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I use **AWS Elastic Beanstalk** for a **Python** application.

In this application I have some long requests (requests that take more than 1 minute to respond). When I deployed the application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk I received, for these requests, *504 HTTP status code*.

As a first step I changed the **idle timeout** value in LoadBalancer settings (classic LoadBalancer).
I solved my problem but now I see some confusion about the status of my associated EC2 instances (for example these often go down and I see in the Apache logs many `408 status codes` from internal AWS network... I think from my load balancer).

In this [article](https://jaxenter.com/troubleshooting-aws-elastic-beanstalk-134700.html) (or [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-error-message.html#ts-elb-errorcodes-http504)), I reed that, probably, I have to change the *Apache keep-alive timeout* (inside my Elastic Beanstalk instances) also but I'm not sure what to add to my .ebextensions configuration files
I don't found specific indications in the documentation. Some idea?